# why is open function only reading the last line of my file

Tags: python, file, file-handling

```
file=open('ssss.txt','r')
dict1=dict()
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.lower()
    words = line.split(" ") 
for word in words:
    if word in dict1:
        dict1[word]=dict1[word]+1
    else:
        dict1[word]=1
#print(sorted(dict1.items(), key=lambda kv:kv[1]))
print(dict1)
print("The top 10 words with maximum occurence are:")
```

this is txt file
[txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ek0Xj.png)
output
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9OdU.png)

I want it to return a dictionary with all words not just the last line

Comment: FWIW, `open` doesn't read anything. The part that actually reads your file line-by-line is the `for line in file` loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.lower()
    words = line.split(" ") 
for word in words:
```

The second `for` will only run after the first one. By then, `words` is left with what was on the last line. You probably want:

```
file=open('ssss.txt','r')
dict1=dict()
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.lower()
    words = line.split(" ") 
    for word in words:
        if word in dict1:
            dict1[word]=dict1[word]+1
        else:
            dict1[word]=1

print(dict1)
print("The top 10 words with maximum occurence are:")
```

Notice, now, the second loop is nested under the first one. So, the processing of words will happen for every line.

Comment: thanks i guess it was a stupid indentation fault

Answer (score 1):

You are reading every line. You are only *saving* the words from the last line, though, with `words = line.split(" ")`. You need to accumulate the words from every line in a list.

```
from collections import Counter


with open('ssss.txt') as file:
    words = []
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip().lower()
        words.extend(line.split(" "))

    # words = [word for line in file for word in line.strip().lower().split(" ")]

d = Counter(words)
```

Or, as [@Jeffrey shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74705272/1126841), update the counter as you read each line. Adapted to use `collections.Counter`, it might look like

```
from collections import Counter


d = Counter()
with open('ssss.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip().lower()
        d.update(line.split(" "))
```